# "Using" directives inside classes

Tags: c++, namespaces

Following my previous [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309685/importing-namespaces-inside-another-namespace). I've settled on using `using` directives to alias types inside my classes to avoid importing other stuff and polluting other headers that use these offending headers.

```
namespace MyLibrary {
    namespace MyModule1 {
        class MyClass1 {
        public:
            float X;
            float Y;

            MyClass1(float x, float y): X(x), Y(y) {}
        };
    } // namespace MyModule1

    namespace MyModule2 {
        class MyClass2 {
        private:
            // as suggested in linked question
            using MyCustomType1 = MyLibrary::MyModule1::MyClass1;

        public:
            void DoSomething(MyCustomType1 parameter) {
                std::cout << parameter.X << std::endl;
                std::cout << parameter.Y << std::endl;
            }
        };
    } // namespace MyModule2
} // namespace MyLibrary

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyLibrary::MyModule1::MyClass1 some_parameter(1.0f, 2.0f);
    MyLibrary::MyModule2::MyClass2 some_var;

    // Can't do this
    // MyLibrary::MyModule2::MyClass2::MyCustomType1 some_other_var;

    // But I can do this
    some_var.DoSomething(some_parameter);
    return 0;
}
```

How will the users outside of the `MyLibrary` namespace know what is `MyCustomType1` if it is aliased inside a class (privately)?

Is my usage here of `using` legal, or is this a dirty hack I'm accidentally doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will know for the simple reason you have to `#include` the declarations of both classes.

Having read this, and the previous question, I think the missing concept here is the concept of forward declarations.

Consider the following header file, let's called this file `mymodule1_fwd.H`:

```
namespace MyLibrary {
    namespace MyModule1 {
        class MyClass1;
    } // namespace MyModule1
}
```

That's it. This is sufficient for you to declare `MyClass2`:

```
#include "mymodule1_fwd.H"

namespace MyModule2 {
    class MyClass2 {
    private:
        // as suggested in linked question
        using MyCustomType1 = MyLibrary::MyModule1::MyClass1;

    public:
        void DoSomething(MyCustomType1 parameter);
    };
} // namespace MyModule2
```

Note that including this header file only will not really automatically get the entire `MyModule` class declaration. Also note the following:

You can't define the contents of the inline `DoSomething`() class method, because it actually uses the aliased type. This has the following consequences:

- You have to define the `DoSomething`() method somewhere, in some way, probably inside the `.C` implementation translation module.
- Similarly, you have to have declare the actual `MyClass1` class from the `mymodule1_fwd.H` header file. I am using my own personal naming convention here, "filename_fwd.H" for forward declarations, the forward declaration header file; and "filename.H" for the actual class implementation, the implementation header file.
- Callers of the `DoSomething`() method will have to explicitly `#include` the actual class declaration header file for `MyClass`, since they have to pass it as a parameter.

You can't really avoid the fact that the callers have to know the class that they're actually using to pass parameters. But only the callers of the `DoSomething`() method will need that. Something that uses other parts of the `MyClass2`, and don't invoke `DoSomething`(), don't need to know anything about `MyClass1`, and the actual class declaration won't be visible to them unless they explicitly `#include` the class implementation header file.

Now, if you still need `DoSomething`() to be inlined, for performance reasons, there are a couple of tricks that can be used, with preprocessor directives, that if someone `#include`s all the necessary header files, they'll get the inlined declaration of the `DoSomething`() method.

But that'll have to be another question.